# Яндекс.Карты - убрать границы между регионами

Tags: javascript, jquery, yandex-maps-api

Использую *Яндекс.Карты* для отображения нескольких регионов сразу как одно целое. Можно как-нибудь убрать внутренние границы между ними и оставить лишь общую внешнюю? Код с примером прилагаю.

Заранее спасибо!

```js
YMaps.jQuery(function() {
  var map = new YMaps.Map(YMaps.jQuery("#YMapsID")[0]);
  map.setCenter(new YMaps.GeoPoint(55.617671, 53.552283), 5);
  var zoom = new YMaps.Zoom();
  map.addControl(zoom);
  map.enableScrollZoom(true);
  YMaps.Regions.load("ru", function(state, response) {
    if (state == YMaps.State.SUCCESS) {
      var shapes, polygon;
      var regionVba = response.filter(function(obj) {
        var names = [
          "Республика Башкортостан",
          "Оренбургская область",
          "Пермская область",
          "Республика Татарстан",
          "Удмуртская Республика"
        ];
        return (names.indexOf(obj.name) > -1);
      });
      for (var i = 0; i < regionVba.length; i++) {
        shapes = regionVba[i].metaDataProperty.encodedShapes;
        for (var ix = shapes.length; ix--;) {
          polygon = YMaps.Polygon.fromEncodedPoints(
            shapes[ix].coords,
            shapes[ix].levels
          );
          polygon.setStyle({
            polygonStyle: {
              fillColor: "b00c0c50",
              strokeColor: "b00c0c"
            }
          });
          polygon.setOptions({ hasHint : true });
          polygon.name = "Как убрать внутренние границы?";
          map.addOverlay(polygon);
        }
      }
    } else {
      alert("Error: " + response.error.message)
    }
  });
})
```

```html
<head>
  <title>Несколько регионов.</title>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <script src="https://api-maps.yandex.ru/1.1/index.xml?modules=regions" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="YMapsID" style="width:700px;height:460px"></div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно попробовать склеить границы регионов в один контур через http://turfjs.org/docs#union
и потом показать финальный полигон на карте

Answer (score 0):

Реализовать задачу на самом деле можно, и достаточно просто. К сожалению модуль регионов Яндекс.Карт для этого немного не подойдет, но у него есть почти что drop-in замена - https://github.com/esosedi/regions
Данные по регионам доступны "как сервис", или как отедельный пакет, который можно себе скачать через npm или unpkg - https://github.com/esosedi/osme-geometry

В твоем случае можно или просто федеральный округ попросить (см http://data.esosedi.org), или именно что "склеить" несколько регионово по некому признаку (общий родитель/общая граница) - смотри пример с барселоной в readme регионов.